# Why does a Python list not have unique indices for contiguous duplicate elements?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I was storing a list with elements

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

When I iterated through it and printed each element's index, my output was something like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

I just thought if it was printing just the elements so I tried one more input

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and this time I got proper indexes like

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Why happened in the first case and how can I solve this?

```
n=input()

l=list(input().split())

print(l)

for i in l:
      print(l.index(i))
```

Expected Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Actual Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

Comment: If you want the index of the item you are iterating over, why not use `enumerate`?

Comment: There's nothing to "solve".  `index()` returns the _first_ location of the given value.  If you don't want that, don't use `index()`.

Answer (score 1):

**The `.index` function doesn't work as you expected.**

`.index()` doesn't return the index of the item in the array, it returns you the *first index* or location of the value (see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm)).

In your code

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

for i in l:
      print(l.index(i)) #i is the value itself
```

What's actually happening is that each time it's searching for the first occurrence of the value `i`. In the list `l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`, when you reach the last 4, you actually ask Python to give you the "first occurrence of `4` in the list `l`", so Python gives you the "index" 4.

In JavaScript, it'll be the equivalent of `array.indexOf(val)`.

**What you seem to be looking for is the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function**:

```
for ind, val in enumerate(l):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`list_name.index(i)` returns the index of the first occurrence that element.

So, if your list was:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,5]
```

And you printed out `l.index(i)` by iterating over the list, the output would be.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
4
```

Because 5 has the first occurrence at position 4 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` if you would like to get the position of the elements in the list.

Or, if you just want to print the values:

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20index

> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of **the first item** whose value
> is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

> enumerate(iterable, start=0)
>
> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator,
> or some other object which supports iteration. The **next**() method
> of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
> count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
> iterating over iterable.